# Why didn't Wolf / Death show up on the map to the Wishing Star

Tags: puss-in-boots

In the movie *Puss in Boots: The Last Wish* (2022), Puss is haunted and chased by the embodiment of death throughout the movie, including in the Dark Forest.

Characters use a magic map to navigate the Dark Forest to the Wishing Star. The map supposedly shows any characters / groups inside the forest. If this assumption is correct, why do we never see Death / the Wolf on the map? (After the protagonists enter the forest, the map can be seen at 55:50 as well as 1:09:00, with the Wolf appearing near the protagonists around the same time).

Why isn't the Wolf visible on the map?

Comment: "The map supposedly shows any characters / groups inside the forest"? Well, apparently not. That's a fact and answer should be based on facts not possibilities.